# How to sort coordinates of located feature points of a picture for further use matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting, coordinates, feature-detection

I need some help with matlab and detected features. I'll start with the fact that I am not so good with matlab.

I am trying to automate morphing process by combining feature point detection with morph. I use *CascadeObjectDetector* to find the features of a human face for two images and I find their strongest features and position with *Location* function. What I need is to sort the x,y coordinates of detected features so that coordinates of points in pic1 would match the nearest coordinates of pic2 because the main thing in morphing is to have pairs of corresponding points.

Comment: You want to sort them or find the nearest point from pic1 to each one in pic2?

Comment: I want to find the nearest point.